# Java For-Loop Number Series

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to print a number series that divides by 2 which would result in an output of 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

```
int num = 128;
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    int prevNum = 0;
    prevNum = num / 2;

    System.out.print(prevNum);
    System.out.print(", ");         
}
```

Clearly my current code isn't working as it is only outputting the number 64 eight times. I'm not sure how I can throw away the initial number after printing it and only use the stored number after the division

Comment: what is number?declare `int prevNum` outside.you don't need `prevNum`.just use number.`num = num / 2;`

Comment: First thing first. Take `prevNum` outside. And then inside the for loop use `prevNum = prevNum / 2` and define `prevNum` as `128` outside

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add my initial number which is int num = 128;

Comment: Also would suggest to use while loop and make it run until prevNum != 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code that you have posted, I feel that you have initialised `num` as 128 somewhere in your code.

Now in your loop you are storing `prevNum` as `num/2` in other words `128/2` each time in the loop. So you are getting `64` as output 8 times as your loop loops 8 times.

The correction I would suggest in this code is you do not require the second variable `prevNum`. Simply use `num = num/2` and print the value of `num` variable. This will solve your problem.

A better code for this loop would be :

```
int num = 128;
while (num > 1) // This takes care of the loop. 
                //Also if you write num = 256, then also this loop would work.
{
    num = num / 2;

    System.out.print(num);
    System.out.print(", ");         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `prevNum` to `num`, this will change the value of `num`, but it works.

Or declare `prevNum` outside the loop this way: `int preNum = num;`, and replace line 4 to `prevNum = prevNum / 2;`

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 128;
        int prevNum = num;
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{

    prevNum = prevNum / 2;

    System.out.print(prevNum);
    System.out.print(", ");         
}
```

This is in logic to the way you are working with. But, there are more efficient ways to get the same result.

OP, you initialized prevNum=0 inside the for-loop and doing so, for each iteration, it was getting assigned to the value 0. What you actually wanted was to carry over the quotient of the previous division to the next iteration. So in order to do that, the prevNum was intilaized outside the loop with value set to num(i.e; 128). And in each iteration, prevNum is getting divided by 2, and the result is assigned back to prevNum.

Comment: Point out what is wrong in the OP's code and how your code corrects it. Please don't just spoon feed.

Comment: @Blip Sorry, added description.

Answer (score 1):

Without local variables outside of the loop:

```
for (int i = 128; i > 0; i = i / 2) System.out.print(i + (i > 1 ? ", " : ""));
```

We loop over i starting with the initial value `128` and dividing by 2 each iteration (`i = i / 2`).
Then the current value of `i` is printed and appended with `,` if `i > 1` is satisfied.

Output:

```
128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 128;
int prevNum = num; // modify here.
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    prevNum = prevNum / 2;

    System.out.print(prevNum);
    System.out.print(", ");         
}
```

**Edit**:
**You are not reducing the actual number. On each iteration you are dividing same number again. But you should divide this prevNum by 2 on each iteration.**

Hope this help.

Comment: this answer is not helpful for the OP to understand the problem in his code. Please give some explanation as to why this would work and his code would not work.